# Иерархия объектов(квадратов) sfml c++

Tags: c++, sfml, hierarchy

Решил попробовать sfml. Понадобилось сделать объект из нескольких квадратов. Нужно, чтобы он поворачивался,как один объект. Как? Есть пример кода?
Насколько я понял по документации нужно сделать иерархию с помощью класса, но как построить дочерние квадраты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать **граф сцены**, и, если в sfml нет его дефолтной реализации, как например в UE4/Unity, можно сделать самому. Пример тут, в конце: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-transform.php

Чтобы понять происходящее, нужно минимально осознать применение матриц.

1. Матрица 4х4 (sf::Transform - её обертка) хранит позицию, ориентацию и масштабирование объекта.
2. Перемножение двух матриц даст новую матрицу, комбинирующую позицию/ориентацию/масштабирование первых двух -  **это и используется для позиционирование дочерних объектов относительно родительского**. **Порядок перемножения важен**, справа налево: `result = mat_3 * mat_2 * mat_1`.
3. [Под капотом] Итоговая матрица перемножается на каждую вершину рисуемого объекта (прямоугольник спрайта в данном случае), в результате вершины искажаются так, словно мы видим подвинутый/повернутый/сжатый (в зависимости от содержания матрицы) объект.

*Поправка: так как SFML - 2D библиотека, sf::Transform представляет матрицу 3х3, а не 4х4.*

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что должно быть вместо
`// ... functions to transform the node` и

`// ... functions to manage the node's children`

Comment: 1. Там m_transform приватный, если нужно изменить m_transform узла извне, нужно прокинуть соответствующие методы, вроде setPosition, setRotation.

2. Так как список дочерних узлов m_children тоже приватный, если извне нужно добавить дочерние элементы узлу, так же нужен метод вроде addChildren.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1247946/402812 - похожий вопрос по теме.